# Override form.save() to not create new record but update existing record in db table each time it is executed

Tags: django, django-views

I was trying hard to prevent the creation of new row in the database table when I save the form in my view.

I have below code in my view

```
def checker(request):
  response_data=''
  if request.method == "POST":
    user_form1 = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
    if user_form1.is_valid(): 
        new_form = user_form1.save(commit=False)
        new_form.save()  # Image file gets uploaded in the server and new row gets created each time this gets executed
        user_form1.save_m2m()
        res=td_tab.objects.filter(id=request.session.get('proid')).update(profpicpath=new_form.profpicpath.url)
        response_data = 'Updated response'
else:
    form = DocumentForm() 
    response_data = 'Nothing to update!'
return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="text/plain")
```

Form :

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    profpicpath = forms.FileField()
    class Meta:
        model = td_tab
        fields = ('profpicpath',)
```

model has several fields apart from profpicpath.

The problem is, in my view when new_form.save() gets executed, it is creating new record in the database table :(

I want the existing record to be updated for specific proid.. 
surprisingly, below line doesn't work in view.. even if i make it work, new row gets created and only profpicpath field is getting populated in the database table with the latest entry :(

```
res=td_tab.objects.filter(id=request.session.get('proid')).update(profpicpath=new_form.profpicpath.url)
```

How can I prevent creation of new record in td_tab table on every request that is made for checker view ?

Or may be is there some trick to override save() method for form, such that it just updates the existing record rather creating new record for each of its execution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the model instance to update to the form object:

```
your_instance = Model.objects.get(some_data=some_data)
form = DocumentForm(request.POST or None, instance=your_instance)

if form.is_valid():
   ...
   ...
   form.save()
```